# New blog posts don't update on page - How to force update of cookies more frequently?

Tags: cache, cookies

An issue I am encountering is that even after I make a new post, any user who has visited my website recently isn't able to see my updated blog posts.

They only see the old posts. It is **only** after they clear their cookies that they are able to view the latest post.

I know I can't force a user's cache to be cleaned, but there must be some way to maybe shorten the lifespan of those cookies.

Comment: Are you sure it’s about cookies?

Comment: Empty the cache of your caching plugin and revise it's settings.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I am postulating that it is about cookies since clearing mine rectifies the issue.

Comment: like @max-yudin wrote - sounds like a cache. What cache plugins if any do you have activated? On your hosts control/hosting panel, are there any mentions of cache? Many expensive as well as cheap shared hosts have caching for increased speed/performance of WP sites, but they don't always make it clear to users that they're doing it.